# WP_Query's WHERE updated, but Search Results are not updated

Tags: posts-where

I am pretty new to WordPress here, and I have seen the way to add condition into the query is by adding below inside functions.php:

```
add_filter('posts_where', 'add_where');
function add_where( $where ) {
    global $wpdb;

    $post_title = get_query_var( 'post_title', FALSE );
    $where .= " AND {$wpdb->prefix}posts.post_title LIKE '%$post_title%'";
    
    return $where;
}
```

For the record, I have added 'post_title' in the query vars as well.

So when I trigger the search and when I printed the query, it is actually showing the query like what I wanted, for example I want to find posts where the post title consist of 'vascular' :

```sql
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts WHERE 1=1 AND wp_posts.post_type IN ('post', 'page', 'attachment') AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'acf-disabled' OR wp_posts.post_author = 2 AND wp_posts.post_status = 'private') AND wp_posts.post_title LIKE '%vascular%' ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 10
```

However, the search result is showing all posts.

Here is the link for it: http://verztec-online.com/clients/annals/?s=&post_title=vascular

I am not sure what am I missing here.

Comment: Which query are you printing? You change doesn't have any conditions, so it is going to apply to all queries run on every page.

Comment: Hi jacob,

i am printing out this variable:
```
print_r($GLOBALS['wp_query']->request);
```

and yes, i have updated the code by adding it like this 
```
if( $query->is_search ) {
    $where .= " AND {$wpdb->prefix}posts.post_title LIKE '%$post_title%'";
}
```